# 1 Article has many posts SQL Group By Error

Tags: sql, sql-server

Here are the 3 tables that are included in this querystatement

- Posts:Id,Title,Post,RatingId,Img
- Rating:Id,UserId,PostId

1 post has multiple ratings,we want to count the ratings along with all the information about the article itselfs.

This is what I have:

```
SELECT p.*, Count(r.PostId)
FROM Posts p INNER JOIN
     Rating r
     on p.RatingId = r.PostId
```

Then I get this error:

> Msg 8120, Level 16, State 1, Line 1 Column 'Posts.Id' is invalid in
>   the select list because it is not contained in either an aggregate
>   function or the GROUP BY clause.

But I don't want to use a group by, I want to return the article information along with a column of the count of the rating of that article.

Thanks!

Comment: Your data structure doesn't make much sense to me.  Can you edit your question and provide sample data and desired results.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Probably the simplest way to do what you want is with a subquery:

```
SELECT p.*,
       (SELECT Count(r.PostId)
        FROM rating r
        WHERE p.RatingId = r.PostId
       )
FROM Posts p ;
```

Your query has a problem because it uses an aggregation function `COUNT()` and other columns (`p.*`) and there is no `GROUP BY` clause.

Also, your `JOIN` condition looks really strange.  I would expect `p.PostId = r.PostId` or `p.Id = r.PostId`.